# BuddyPress: What is the use of is_default_option field in wp_bp_xprofile_fields table?

Tags: buddypress

In BuddyPress, What is the use of is_default_option field in wp_bp_xprofile_fields table?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is one of the things you won't find in the docs, but only in the source. The source code contains only one usage of this variable. This is in [bp-xprofile-template.php](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/buddypress/nav.html?bp-xprofile/bp-xprofile-template.php.source.html) line 493.

```
              // First, check to see whether the user-entered value matches
              if ( in_array( $allowed_options, (array) $option_values ) ) {
                  $selected = ' selected="selected"';
              }

              // Then, if the user has not provided a value, check for defaults
              if ( !is_array( $original_option_values ) && empty( $option_values ) && $options[$k]->is_default_option ) {
                  $selected = ' selected="selected"';
              }
```

As you can see, it is used to pre-select an option in the case the user hasn't supplied a value yet.